# keepass web interface

Tags: web-applications, password-management

I'm just getting started with Keepass http://keepass.info/ as a password database. It works great as an standalone application.

The problem I'm having is when I am with out MY computer or USB key and I need to get a password out of the database.

Currently I am keeping a copy of my password database on my Webserver (Secret URL). When I am at a friends house and I need a password. I download the database file and run keepass on their computer, Get the password, and delete the database file. This is a little clumsy as sometime people will not let me download Executable to their computers.

What I am looking for is a semi secure online version that uses keepass's database (without having to covert the database). Something I can self hosted.

I have tried http://ossfree.net/webkeepass/ but it requires you to convert the KeePass database to XML for import in to the online web-app. I'm looking for something that can read directly from the database.

I noticed that there are many different ports of KeyPass available I was hoping for a Java applet version that i could just embed in to a website with out too much installation but it does not seem to exist at the moment.

Requirements

- Uses KeePass database (no conversion)
- Self hosted.

Comment: This question belongs on superuser.  Don't repost it as once enough people vote it will automatically be migrated.

Comment: @3dinfluence Not quite, as shopping/recommendation question are also [off topic](http://superuser.com/faq) there, just as they are [here](http://serverfault.com/faq)

Answer (score 3):

Are you dead set on Keepass?  I recently switched from Keepass due to some of the same frustrations.  I even use [dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) to keep my keepass database in a handy place and sync between my computers.  But in the end that's just a bandaid.

I ended up switching to [lastpass](http://lastpass.com/).  They have a web vault for accessing your passwords from any browser without plugins if you're away from your computer.  But they also integrate into every browser on any OS via plugins and they have smart phone apps.

Then for when you have a usb thumb drive with you then you can use the portable version of firefox on it with the lastpass plugin loaded.

Comment: *Not self hosted, I'm paranoid about others having access to my data. very paranoid. although their service looks pretty convincing

Comment: I'm with you there but I made the switch after doing a lot of research and these guys seem to be up to speed on security.  Your passwords are stored on their server encrypted with your key.  So this isn't much different than using keepass and storing your password db on a website in a "secret" location. There are many ways to discover files on a server if they are inside the webroot so your secret file isn't as secret as you think it is.  Given that you can require 2 factor authentication with lastpass I would argue that this is more secure than what you're currently doing now.

Comment: Have a look at http://lastpass.com/whylastpass_technology.php and https://lastpass.com/support_faqs.php#safer and then ask yourself is your current solution of self hosting an encrypted db file is able to provide the same level of security.

Comment: @3dinfluence Can you please be more specific ? I can't understand if you are pro or against Lastpass.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread but it comes up high on Google.

This seems to be exactly what you want:

[WebKeePass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkeepass/)

Description from the site:

> Web AND Mobile (Apple iPhone) based, multi user, java port of the KeePass project. A free, easy to use password manager which helps you to manage your passwords in a secure way. Focused on deep encryption and ease of use.

One potential drawback is that this thing requires a java plugin in the browser.

Comment: A bit more info would make this useful for future visitors.  A lonk only will not help if the link changes in the future.

Comment: OK added more info, though if the link is broken I'm not sure how the info will be useful!